# useEffect not triggers when rendering a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, frontend, use-effect

I am clicking on a single post on homepage that'll send me to the clicked post's page. At this component's rendering I am dispatching an action from useEffect that will get the post data from backend. But useEffect doesn't gets triggered even a single time but page render's twice.
Please help

```js
import {
  Container,
  Typography,
  LinearProgress,
  CircularProgress,
  Paper
} from '@material-ui/core';
import React, {
  useEffect
} from 'react';
import {
  getPost
} from "../../actions/posts";
import Navbar from '../Navbar/Navbar';
import {
  useDispatch,
  useSelector
} from 'react-redux';
import {
  useParams
} from 'react-router-dom';
import useStyles from "./styles";

const PostDetails = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const {
      id
    } = useParams();
    const classes = useStyles();
    const {
      post,
      isLoading
    } = useSelector((state) => (state.posts));

    console.log(post);
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log(post);
      dispatch(getPost(id));
    }, [id, dispatch]);

    return ( < div >
        <
        Navbar color = "#808080" / > {
          isLoading ? ( < div > < LinearProgress / > < /div>) : 
            ( < Container className = {
                classes.root
              } >
              <
              Typography variant = "h1" > {
                post.title
              } < /Typography> <
              /Container>)}</div > )
          }
          export default PostDetails
```

My action:

```js
export const getPost = (id) => async(dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: "START_LOADING"
    });
    const {
      data
    } = await api.fetchPost(id);
    dispatch({
      type: "FETCH_POST",
      payload: {
        post: data
      }
    });
    dispatch({
      type: "END_LOADING"
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

reducer:

```js
export default (state = {
  isLoading: true,
  posts: []
}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "START_LOADING":
      return { ...state,
        isLoading: true
      };

    case "FETCH_POST":
      return { ...state,
        post: action.payload.post
      };

    case "FETCH_ALL":
      return { ...state,
        posts: action.payload.data,
        currentPage: action.payload.currentPage,
        numberOfPages: action.payload.numberOfPages
      };

    case "CREATE":
      return { ...state,
        posts: [...state.posts, action.payload]
      };

    case "END_LOADING":
      return { ...state,
        isLoading: false
      };

    default:
      return "";
  }
}
```

My backend is fine since when i run the api request on localhost to backend it sends me a JSON object with post's data.

Comment: What does "useEffect doesn't gets triggered even a single time" mean?

Comment: It don't gets triggered on the initial render but I am getting 2 console.log values both undefined and console.log inside useEffect not triggers. This means that component rendered twice but useEffect was not triggered.

Answer (score 4):

UseEffect gets triggered only when the values given inside the square brackets change. So, if you want it to get triggered only when loading the page for the first time, leave it blank.

```
useEffect(() => {
      console.log(post);
      await dispatch(findPost(id));
    }, []);
```

Comment: It didn't worked. I am getting error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"

Comment: is useeffect working? try console.log inside useeffect

Comment: @NamanKedia Did you read the error? You load "post" from state, but your selector loads "posts" plural.

Comment: Actually i have used combineReducer which consists of user, posts states. And even if I try this I get an error "PostDetails.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'post' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined."

Comment: Did you add await since dispatch() is an async function?

Comment: await is added in the action

Comment: Please someone help! I had earlier made a similae web app but there was not such problem and I have even compared the code. Please help

Comment: @NamanKedia oops my mistake was not importing use effect lol try that

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch(findPost(id)); //No findPost in ../../actions/posts
```

There is no **findPost** action. Do you think you should change it to **getPost**

```
dispatch(getPost(id));
```